# Why is my middleman heroku app ignoring the Procfile?

Tags: heroku, middleman, puma, procfile

I've been struggling trying to launch my middleman repo to heroku. I've followed a tutorial http://randomerrata.com/post/56163474367/middleman-on-heroku, but have had continued issues. Although installing the puma gem, for some reason the procfile is being ignored and the heroku app keeps pointing to 
     web bundle exec sudo unicorn_rails -c ./config/unicorn.rb -p $PORT -D --env production

Any idea how to get this thing to stop pointing to the unicorn rails and use puma?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would be worth checking out [middleman-heroku](https://github.com/middleman/middleman-heroku) as a different route to take. Alternatively I would check that your `Gemfile.lock` is up to date and committed.

Answer (score 0):

I would try tailing the logs with `heroku logs -t` to see if you can see what's happening.

Is your Procfile called **Procfile** with a capital P?

What does it look like, can you post it here?

My Procfile has `web: bundle exec puma -p $PORT`. Is Puma listed in your Gemfile?